# Simple Metaprogramming some getters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

i'm trying to create some getters via metaprogramming,but for some reason it does not seems to work. I'm doing this :

```
RESOURCES = %w(wood stone gold)

class << self
    RESOURCES.each do |resource|
        define_method "#{resource}" do
            resource
        end
    end
end
```

Inside a rails application, but i get a wood undefined method, upon executing. Any ideas why ?

(That code is inside a Rails "class City < ActiveRecord::Base" class)

Comment: `attr_reader RESOURCES` would be just fine

Comment: there is actually more customization inside the define_methods, resource is just there to make the question simpler. But it's internally more elaborate due to the fact that i'm using an association. But good remark anyway.

Comment: It's actually like this now, if it can be read as a comment here :)    define_method "#{resource}" do   
    eval("#{resource}_production_amount")
   end

Comment: don't forget `send` is a safer way to code. I can't see any problem in your current context but it's a good habit.

Comment: yeah, you are right, i just stuck with eval here because it's just static not user related content, but i definitely agree with send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a class method, not an instance method.

Watch what happens when you try:

```
City.wood
=> "wood"
```

Assuming you want it to be an instance method:

```
RESOURCES = %w(wood stone gold)

RESOURCES.each do |resource|
    define_method "#{resource}" do
        resource
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a class method wood, not an instance method.  You would need to call

```
City.wood
```

If you call define_method outside of the class << self, you will be defining instance methods.

```
class City < Object
  RESOURCES = %w(wood stone gold)
  RESOURCES.each do |resource|
    define_method "#{resource}" do
      resource
    end
  end  
end
city = City.new
puts city.wood
```